# How do I play lead of a song with metronome?

Tags: guitar, lead-guitar

It's hard to count 1234 while leading?

Comment: That's why you have to internalize the beat - know where you are without consciously counting.  See also [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/73978/how-can-i-learn-to-play-fills-and-licks-without-losing-track-of-the-time-signatu/73981#73981).

Answer (score 1):

It's what you don't do! As long as you're aware of where beat 1 is, that's all you need. Tapping a foot, nodding a head, shrugging a shoulder.

If you have a metronome with a 'ding' available on beat one, set it.

Chords usually change on each bar, and often every four bars a new line will occur, so you should be aware of that. Presumably you're playing with a band, so get the drummer to do something special at the beginning of each line, which is probably where you'll end one phrase and start another. A splash cymbal for example.